# Error when inserting data into a database

Tags: postgresql

For school we needed to create a database. I wrote the code to create the database but i have problems with inserting data into it. I always get the same error.

> ERROR:  insert or update on table "gebruikers" violates foreign key constraint "fk_gebruikers_afspeellijsten"
>   DETAIL:  Key (userid)=(1) is not present in table "afspeellijsten".
>   SQL state: 23503

I created the "gebruikers" and the "afspeellijsten" tables likes this:

```
CREATE SCHEMA GROEP10;
CREATE TABLE GROEP10.Gebruikers
(
        userID          INTEGER         PRIMARY KEY,
    name            VARCHAR(45)     NOT NULL,
    wachtwoord      VARCHAR(45)     NOT NULL,
    mail            VARCHAR(45)     UNIQUE  NOT NULL,
    birthDate       DATE            NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_Gebruikers_Afspeellijsten FOREIGN KEY ( userID ) REFERENCES GROEP10.Afspeellijsten (userID)
);

CREATE TABLE GROEP10.Afspeellijsten
(
    afspeellijstID  INTEGER         PRIMARY KEY,
    name            VARCHAR(45)     NOT NULL,
    creationDate    DATE            NOT NULL,
    userID          INTEGER         NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_Afspeellijsten_Gebruikers UNIQUE ( userID ),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Afspeellijsten_AfspeellijstHasSingle FOREIGN KEY ( afspeellijstID ) REFERENCES GROEP10.AfspeellijstHasSingle ( afspeellijstID )
);
```

I try to insert data into gebruikers like this:

```
INSERT INTO gebruikers
VALUES (
    1,
    'Jonas',
    'OK',
    'ZZZ@hotmail.com',
    '03/03/2000'
);
```

Comment: This error is suggesting that your `GROEP10.Afspeellijsten` table doesn't have a record containing `userID` of `1`. It has to exist there first in order to insert into `GROEP10.Gebruikers` because of your foreign key constraint. That's what *"DETAIL: Key (userid)=(1) is not present in table "afspeellijsten"."* is saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your table `Gebruikers` you have a **FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT** for `userID`

```
CONSTRAINT fk_Gebruikers_Afspeellijsten FOREIGN KEY ( userID ) 
   REFERENCES GROEP10.Afspeellijsten (userID)
```

That mean before you can insert into `Gebruikers` you have to create `userID = 1`  in `Afspeellijsten`